# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, azure, .net-assembly, .net-4.7, .net-4.7.1

While trying to configure the AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder for my .NET Framework 4.7.1 application I am getting the following error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

I don't know why this is occurring. I cloned my git project to another directory and re-installed the Azure nuget packages but it is still happening. Am I supposed to setup configuration somewhere else? I also can't find the Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication, Version=1.0.1.0 in my code.

[image: Web Error]

`web.config bindings`

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.3" newVersion="4.1.1.3" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.5.0" newVersion="3.0.5.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.1.0" newVersion="1.6.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.1" newVersion="4.0.5.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.35.1.0" newVersion="4.35.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.17.0.0" newVersion="1.17.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

`packages.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AddMvc3ToWebForms" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="ASP.NET_MVC_3" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Azure.Core" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Azure.Identity" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="ExchangeWebServices" version="1.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery.BlockUI" version="2.66" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery-vsdoc" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Base" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk" version="4.0.7333.3021" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.35.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal" version="2.18.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="5.2.9" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.mshtml" version="7.0.3300.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.23" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.19" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Northscale.Caching" version="2.0.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NServiceKit.Common" version="1.0.31" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NServiceKit.Redis" version="1.0.20" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NServiceKit.Text" version="1.0.10" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="OctoPack" version="3.0.71" targetFramework="net471" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="RazorGenerator" version="2.1.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Memory.Data" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Private.Uri" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.7.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="toastr" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="UI.for.Asp.Net.Ajax" version="2017.3.913" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity" version="2.1.505.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity.Interception" version="2.1.505.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="0.10" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: check the packages.config. That version may be in there.

Comment: @GHDevOps It is not there. I added `packages.config` and an updated bindings section.

Comment: Your GAC maybe?? Last resort...delete the bin and obj folders from sln

Comment: That package isn't even listed in the GAC. I already tried deleting bin and obj folders but doesn't appear to be working. Is there a way to force a specific version?

Comment: Are there conflicting versions in Nuget? Do a manage on the sln and see if each project has the same assembly version

Comment: I did a manage nuget packages for solution and checked the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` package. I only have it installed in my UI project and it is version 1.6.1.